# Do SEO bots always follow the url in the href attribute of an A tag, even if the click/tap is intercepted with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

Suppose I have a regular A tag with a proper URL in its href attribute (foo.com). Now, suppose I intercept the click (or tap) event of the A with a JavaScript function so, instead of performing the default action (navigate to foo.com) I can do something else first (fade out the content, for example), then navigate to a different URL (otherfoo.com).

1. Would this affect SEO? (meaning, will the bots get confused?)
2. Would the bot follow the url in the href attribute (foo.com) or would it follow through the JavaScript function (and navigate to otherfoo.com)?

By "bots" and "SEO" I am mostly referring to Google, but broader answers would be great as well.

Comment: That's impossible to answer. "SEO Bots" do not *always* do anything, they do whatever they were programmed to do. Each one is different.

Comment: @meagar: I am mostly concerned with Google bots. I have added that to my question.

Answer (score 1):

#### tl:dr

No, typical crawler doesn't evaluate javascript (to that extent) as it, in the effect, serves no real purpose - only more confusion.

#### Disclaimer

Crawlers can probably scan javascript or CSS to obtain other info, which could affect sorting - but this is irrelevant in the scope of this questions.

Further more [**google crawler parses javascript**](http://www.business2community.com/seo/googles-crawler-now-understands-javascript-mean-0898263) but this seems to have effect on generated DOM tree, not callbacks which can be infinitely complex and would leave a gap for unknown state of the output - google wouldn't know if it has the links right or not.

In many javascript interpreters I have noticed a `javascript until onload` scheme used to get proper DOM tree. HTML to PDF creators (the better ones) can be an example. Google will be similar I guess.

#### Thoughts on that

Ultimately, this is up to the implementation. But while it's technically possible to evaluate the javascript on your site and index javascript redirects, it's *highly* error prone and would not serve a practical purpose.

If nothing else, you could bypass check that by passing fake javascript files to the crawler, which usually identifies itself by `User-Agent` header.

Definitely do not rely on this. I think you should make a hidden (to the user) link to any content you want to index but is linked by javascript. Use hiding by CSS class though, in case some search engine thought it's smart to ignore inline style `display:block` nodes.

```
<a href="javascript.php" class="only-seen-by-crawlers">Javascript linked page</a>
```

Or just generally don't use javascript on links as it makes no sense in sane scenarios.

Comment: +1 for your detailed answer... although disagree with the "makes no sense in sane scenarios" part. In my particular scenario, which I have simplified for the sake of this question, it does make sense. I it is still sane : )

Comment: Well I understand that you have some reasons to do what you do. But your situation is extra ordinary for sure. Implying it's *insane* was just an intentional exaggeration on my side. I'm definitely sure I could find a more suitable workaround for you, but we're not allowed to discuss this there.

Comment: That is OK. I actually want the bots to ignore the JavaScript, so I was hoping for that to be the answer. And, in my particular case, both URLs are the same (foo and otherfoo). I will wait to see if other users have extra input on this.

Comment: We could see some interesting info popping out here (I'm not SEO specialist, just had to optimize few sites) if you could release more of your context. You can use fantasy and make it up into something different to keep your project private. I do this quite often, but it can easily incorporate confusion in your post - but so does being obscure about your intentions.